# What graph model gives this degree distribution?

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, data-analysis, random-graphs, empirical-processes

I have a real world network where I've plotted the degree distribution. If the network was formed from a [Barabási–Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model), the degree distribution should be roughly a power law of the form $P(k)=k^{-3}$. Instead the distribution looks like:

[image]

The peaks of in the tail of the graph are understandable from a physical perspective (in that, I expect a set of abnormally well-connected nodes).

Concerning the rest of the distribution however, I'm perplexed. Are there any graph models that will create a distribution with this shape?

Comment: To me, the weirdness on the right looks like some kind of floating point related issue, especially the distinct horizontal lines.

Comment: The "distinct horizontal lines" come from the fact that the observed degree distributions counts can be 1, 2, 3, ..., which, when converted to the probabilities w.r.t. the rest of the vertices are approximately $10^{-7}$. The vertical lines are coming from a known physical event that I can account for.